# how to fix the below error regarding npm run stubs?

Tags: node.js, stub

getting the below error after installing robohydra after running `npm run stubs`

> ./node_modules/.bin/robohydra ./tests/remote-stubs/stub.conf

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

i'm trying to run npm run stubs to run robohydra packge
but the below error comes up

> ./node_modules/.bin/robohydra ./tests/remote-stubs/stub.conf

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace stubs command with the below command in package.json
"stubs": ".\node_modules\.bin\robohydra .\tests\remote-stubs\stub.conf",

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).